# Signalr Chat logged User Name

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Hello I am trying to get logged member name to signalr chat here is my Index

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var currentMember= @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Name);
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }
</script>
```

instead of this line

```
 $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
```

I tried these

```
$('#displayname').val("@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name");
 $('#displayname').val(currentMember);
```

but these didnt work. So how can I get my logged member Name ?

Comment: Are you logged in ? Is HttpContext.Current is null ? What is happening ?

Comment: yes I'm logged in but I dont know httpContext.current null or not but I can see and error says Uncaught ReferenceError: GearedSkull is not defined. Gearedskull iste user

Comment: I made an alert and my ViewBag.name and "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" works great but this signalr cant get the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this line

```
var currentMember= @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Name);
```

Assume `ViewBag.Name` is returning the string `furkan`. If you check the view source of the page, you will see

```
var currentMember = furkan;
```

Javascript is going to think that furkan is a variable, but it is not!

**Solution** : Wrap your server code with double quotes or single quotes

```
var currentMember= '@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Name)';
```

Now if you check view source of the page, It will be

```
var currentMember = 'furkan';
```

So now currentMember variable stores a string value. You can use it in your code later.

```
var currentMember= '@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Name)';
alert(currentMember);
$('#displayname').val(currentMember);
```

Comment: can you also tell me how can I create a room with button click so I want something like this. I will see users and then when I click on one I will send him a url which is like chat/Index/room1 and only inveted ppl or who every knows that url will be able to join. Trying something like one to one or many to many chat with invite